# Сумма кубов рекурсией - нахождение лучшей суммы кубов

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия

```
def sumOfCubes(n):
if n == 0:
    return
sumOfCubes(n - (int(n ** (1/3))) ** 3)
print((int(n ** (1 / 3)) ** 3), end=' ')


sumOfCubes(int(input()))
```

> Важно! Задача должна решаться рекуррентной функцией.

Задача заключается в представлении натурального числа в виде суммы кубов других 
натуральных чисел, при чем должно быть наименьшее возможное число слагаемых.

> Ввод: 271
>
> Вывод: 1 27 27 216
>
> Ввод: 100
>
> Вывод: 1 8 27 64

Сайт, на который отправляется этот код, сообщает о неправильных ответах.

Программа должна вывести разложение переданного ей числа в виде суммы кубов других натуральных чисел. Эта сумма должна состоять из наименьшего количества слагаемых среди всех таких сумм.

Comment: В вашем вопросе во первых ошибки из за отсутствия форматирования. Во вторых вопрос не понятен, оформите вопрос как положено.

Comment: Исправил. Постарался оформить максимально понятно.

Comment: а вас не смущает, что у вас голый `return`?

Comment: Нет,голый `return` возвращает ничего в предыдущий замороженный фрагмент стека, тем самым не зацикливается рекурсия.

Comment: Тут проблема вот в чем, предположим число (X) - имеет разложение [1 1 1 1 1 275 9980] и [1 1 275 275 7300] ,(здесь я взял условные числа), то надо выводить именно 2 вариант,т.к там меньше кубов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой код должен работать:

```
def main(N:'int>=0'):
    decompositions = []
    cubes = [i*i*i for i in range(int(N**(1/3)), 0, -1)]
    r = to_sum_of_cubes(N, cubes, decompositions)
    print(decompositions[0])
       
def to_sum_of_cubes(N:'int>=0', cubes:list, decompositions:list):
    if N in (0, 1):
        decompositions.append([N])
        return
    if not cubes:
        return
    n = N
    decomposition = []
    for idx in range(len(cubes)):
        while n >= cubes[idx]:
            decomposition.append(cubes[idx])
            n -= cubes[idx]
            
    decompositions.append(decomposition)
    to_sum_of_cubes(N, cubes[1:], decompositions)
    decompositions.sort(key=lambda x: len(x))
    decompositions = [decompositions[0]]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(32)
```

Comment: Из 21 теста не прошло всего 2 при загрузке python файла(Скорее всего проблема компилятора на сайте). Данный алгоритм является рабочим, ибо переписав код на плюсы, тестер выдал 21 из 21.

Comment: @Kolinf можете поделиться кодом на плюсах?

Comment: код не сохранил,но если желаете,могу переписать

Comment: Нашел код решения задачи вообще в 8 строчек.

`void test(int n, int r)
{
    if (r<rmin) if (n==0) rmin=r; else {
        int i, j=n, k;
        do {i=j; j=(2*i + n/i/i)/3;} while (j<i);
        for (; j=n-i*i*i, k=i+1, k*k*k>j; i--) test(j, r+1);
    }
}`

Comment: @Kolinf, спасибо. Не стоит, если не сохранили. Я думал, если остался.

Comment: На самом деле такой алгоритм тоже не является верным. Например, ваш код для числа 273176 выдаёт `[175616, 97336, 216, 8]`, а оптимальным будет `[125000, 74088, 74088]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
def max_cube(n:int)->int: 
    return int(n**(1/3))**3 
    
def sum_of_cubes(n): 
    if n==0: return [0] 
    if n==1: return [1] 
    m = max_cube(n) 
    
    res = [m]+sum_of_cubes(n-m) 
    if (len(res)>1) and (0 in res):
        res.remove(0)
    return res

n = 10**10
res = sum_of_cubes(n)
print(res)
```

Comment: Верно для n = 271, но не верно для остальных тестов,прошло лишь 10\20 тестов.

Comment: @Kolinf для каких не прошло ?

Comment: сайт позволяет проверять входные данные только на учительском аккаунте,по этому входные данные мне не известны.Данная задача граничит с категорией олимпиадных, и видимо по этому там присутствуют достаточно большие числа(вводные данные), которые и не проходят.

Comment: @Kolinf исправил код

Comment: Прошло 12\20 тестов.

Comment: Вот [эта](https://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/statements/view3.php?id=11221&chapterid=112266#1) задача.

Comment: @Kolinf у меня сам алгоритм разложения неверный. Потому и не работает (